# Add default Array list in swagger example

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, enums, swagger

How can I set more then one default value in swagger?

This works :

```
[DefaultValue(CardStatus.Production)]
public IEnumerable<CardStatus>? CardStatuses { get; set; }
```

But I want to set 2 default statuses, is this possible?

```
[DefaultValue([CardStatus.Production, CardStatus.Pending])]
public IEnumerable<CardStatus>? CardStatuses { get; set; }
```

Comment: You tried [DefaultValue(new CardStatus[]{ CardStatus.Production, CardStatus.Pending })? - might work, prob not tho

Comment: Sometimes a guess works, not often tho hahah - ive posted as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[DefaultValue(new CardStatus[]{ CardStatus.Production, CardStatus.Pending })]
```

Comment: Shouldn't the property value also be initialized to actually provide the default values? `[DefaultValue([CardStatus.Production, CardStatus.Pending])]
public IEnumerable<CardStatus> CardStatuses { get; set; } = [CardStatus.Production, CardStatus.Pending];` ?